# How can I merge and format multiple columns which contains int data type in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this (shown below), and I want to create a new column which combines them together (Note that I have other columns which contain numbers):

```
Program Season  Episode 
AAA         1      1
AAA         1      2    
...
...
```

This is the code I tried:

```
#create a new column
series['series_name'] = series[['Program', 'Season','Episode']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(str(x)), axis=1)
```

It gave me something like this:

```
'Program AAA\nSeason 1\nEpisode 1\nName: 0, dtype: object'
```

My expected output should be something like:

```
'AAA-Season 1-Episode 1'
```

Can someone help me, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['series_name'] = df['Program'].str.cat(
    ['Season ' + df['Season'].astype(str),
     'Episode ' + df['Episode'].astype(str)], 
    sep='-'
)
```

Comment: I have other columns which contain numbers, probably not suitable if I set the whole data frame to str

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
df=df1.copy()
df[['Season','Episode']]=df[['Season','Episode']].astype(str).radd(['Season ','Episode '],1)
s=df.apply('-'.join,1)
s
Out[79]: 
0    AAA-Season 1-Episode 1
1    AAA-Season 1-Episode 2
dtype: object
#df1['series_name']=s
```

Comment: I think OP wants it as a separate column without overwriting the others.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 that is just assignment df['New']=s

Comment: You are still modifying the columns